# How do I convert the results of survey::syvratio into a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have calculated ratios for a few variables using svyratio, but it doesn't let me convert the return value into a dataframe. Using DF1 <- as.data.table(loc_ratio), it gives the error

> "Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE,
>   stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :    cannot coerce class
>   ‘"svyratio"’ to a data.frame"

Comment: Please show a small reperoudcible example with `dput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is basically no default method for as.data.frame. What there is only the warning you see:

```
as.data.frame.default  
#====== console output=====
function (x, ...) 
stop(gettextf("cannot coerce class %s to a data.frame", sQuote(deparse(class(x))[1L])), 
    domain = NA)
<bytecode: 0x55e6ce5e1ff0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

So unless the  author of package::`survey` has written an as method, you will see that message. If you know for a fact that the contents of your svyratio value should be a two element list then you might try adding list to the objects class attribute. The `x`-object was built using the first example in the `?svyratio` help page.

```
class(x) <- list("svyratio", "list")
> as.data.frame(x)
        arrests    arrests.1
alive 0.1535064 5.770992e-05
```

In this case the svyratio object was a list of two matrices, but since they only had one element each, the coercion proceeded:

```
> str(x)
List of 2
 $ ratio: num [1, 1] 0.154
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "alive"
  .. ..$ : chr "arrests"
 $ var  : num [1, 1] 5.77e-05
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "alive"
  .. ..$ : chr "arrests"
 - attr(*, "call")= language svyratio.survey.design2(~alive, ~arrests, design = scddes)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "svyratio" "list"
```